# Selecting all countries

Tags: r

I am trying to download data from the below database. I found a way to download data for one country, but I can't found for all countries present in the dataset. Below you can see my data

```
library(IMFData)

IFS.available.codes <- DataStructureMethod("WoRLD")

# Available dimension code
names(IFS.available.codes)

# Define period
databaseID <- "WoRLD"
startdate = "2001-01-01"
enddate = "2021-12-31"
checkquery = FALSE

country_names<-IFS.available.codes$CL_AREA_WoRLD$CodeValue

# Select indicator and country

queryfilter <- list(CL_FREA = "", CL_AREA_WoRLD = c("DE"),  CL_INDICATOR_WoRLD="RTGSE_RM_GDP")
Q.US.NGDP.query <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, 
                                     checkquery)

View(Q.US.NGDP.query)
```

Actually, the main problem is in the argument `CL_AREA_WoRLD`. Here, I want to put all countries. I tried to write `all` but is not functioning.

So the possible solution is to use convert this

```
str(country_names)
 chr [1:203] "AF" "AL" "DZ" "AO" "AI" "AG" "AR" "AM" "AW" "AU" "AT" ....
```

In something like this

```
c("AF","AL","DZ","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU","AT")
```

and put it inside the code with a sign equal to CL_AREA_WoRLD.

So can anybody help how to solve to do this?

Comment: It looks like `country_names` *is* already the vector you need? So just pass it to the function call.

Comment: @dufei It is not work. The vector must be separated with commas and double quotes, something like this c("AF","AL","DZ","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU","AT")

Comment: You can check the data type of `country_names` with `class` and `typeof`. If both is *character*, it is a character vector. What is the datatype of `country_names` instead?

Comment: @cdalitz Type is class(country_names) [1] "character" and structure is   str(country_names)
 chr [1:203] "AF" "AL" "DZ" "AO"... So instead of this in looking for this c("AF","AL","DZ" "AO"...)

Answer (score 0):

As @dufei pointed out, `country_names` already is a character vector and can be passed as such as an argument to your function. If I understand you correctly, however, you do not want to pass the character vector to a function argument, but want to print *R code* as a single character string that does this, maybe for later use or for sharing the code.

The *R code* that implements the constructor of the character vector can be created by hand, e.g., with

```
> x <- c("AF","AL","DZ","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU","AT")
> x_constructor <- sprintf("c(\"%s\")", paste(x, collapse='","'))
```

This is clumsy and requires knowledge of the datatype of the object. Therefore there are builtin functions `dput()` and `deparse()` for creating R construction code from objects. `dput()` only prints the string, but does not return it (the object itself is returned instead), and `deparse()` is a bit tricky because it splits the code into several lines, so it must be combined with `paste` to eventually join the lines again:

```
> x_constructor <- paste(deparse(x), collapse="")
```

Then `x_constructur` will contain the code for constructing the character vector, which you can insert into code that is to be called later, e.g. with `source()`.